# Why QR Code wifi sharing is not showing the wifi password?

Tags: wi-fi, password

I have access to some work-only android devices which they have access to the work wifi and I don't know its wifi password so I tried the QR Code sharing but to my surprize, the plain text which is generated from QR scan doesn't show the password. For comparison, I used this same work-only android device to connect to my hotspot generated from my phone and this time, QR scan from a 3rd device showed the password succssfully. Examples below:

a) plain text after scanning my hotspot:

`WIFI:T:WPA;S:{my_wifi_name_written_here};P:{wifi_password_written_here};;`

b) plain text after scanning work wifi:

`WIFI:T:;S:{work_wifi_name_written_here};P:;;`

So, what is going on here? Is this an advanced setting from network IT administrator? They use Cisco APs (access points) everywhere on my workplace, if that helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the Wi-Fi security (e.g. WPA) used on both the hotspot and work's Wi-Fi?

Comment: Hello,  they are both WPA2-PSK.

Comment: As it is a company WiFi I would guess it uses WPA enterprise authentication instead of PSK. You wrote that is uses WPA2-PSK where do you got this information from?

Comment: @Robert it is shown on wifi list on the work-only-pda android device, when you select this network to view info.

Comment: @bobis That's a bit strange since the QR also doesn't show its encryption type. However, just like Robert, I have a suspicion that it's probably using WPA2-Enterprise, which means [it's using a CA certificate](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-11-break-enterprise-wifi-connection/) instead.